# Data providers issue in phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

This is my data provider function:

```
public function addDataProvider() {
    return [
        [
            [
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'amount' => 800,
            ],
            [
                'currency' => '12312k',
                'amount' => 1201,
            ],
            [
                'currency' => 'DKK',
                'amount' => 1200.01
            ],
            [
                'currency' => 'SEK  ',
                'amount' => 1200.01
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

This is my test function:

```
/**
 * Test case
 * @covers AmountPerCustomer::checkAmounts()
 * @dataProvider addDataProvider
 */
public function testCheckAmountUsingCurrency($query)
{
        ....
        try {
            $ordersPerCustomer->checkAmounts($query['amount'], $query['currency'], $dateInterval);
            $this->fail("Expected Exception has not been raised.");
        }catch (\Exception $error) {
            $this->assertEquals($error->getMessage(), "Total order amount event given parameters exceed sum {$query['amount']} since {$dateInterval->format('H:i d-m-Y')} from source {$source}");
        }
}
```

I am getting this success mesage: `OK (1 test, 1 assertion)` , My question why I have only one assertion. I have multiple array values in my provider . What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: You have one depth of array too many.

Comment: One thing is that the exception raised is probably not the one your expecting, you don't check that the data is fetched properly before you pass it on.

Comment: @localheinz yeah you are right, I wasn't paid attention to the depth of array . Thnx

Comment: By the way, you should probably also use `expectException()` and `expectExceptionMessage()`, hehe!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to returning an array of arrays with arguments for the test method from the data provider, you can also use generators and `yield` an array of arguments instead:

```
public function addDataProvider() : \Generator
{
    $queries = [
        [
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'amount' => 800,
        ],
        [
            'currency' => 'dkk',
            'amount' => 1201,
        ],
        [
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'amount' => 1201,
        ],
        [
            'currency' => 'sek',
            'amount' => 1200.01,
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        yield [
            $query,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then it might be easier to see what is going on, and less array nesting is required.

#### Note

It might also make more sense for you to use `expectException()` and `expectExceptionMessage()` in your test:

```
public function testCheckAmountUsingCurrency($query)
{
    // ...

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage(sprintf(
        'Total order amount event given parameters exceed sum %s since %s from source %s',
        $query['amount'],
        $dateInterval->format('H:i d-m-Y'),
        $source          
    ));

    $ordersPerCustomer->checkAmounts(
        $query['amount'], 
        $query['currency'], 
        $dateInterval
    );
}
```

For reference, see

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As @localheinz suggested in the comments, it is a depth of array issue. This is how my array should look like:

```
public function addDataProvider() {
    return [
        [
            [
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'amount' => 800,
            ]
        ],
        [
            [
                'currency' => 'dkk',
                'amount' => 1201,
            ],
        ],
        [
            [
                'currency' => 'GBP',
                'amount' => 1201,
            ],
        ],
        [
            [
                'currency' => 'sek',
                'amount' => 1200.01,
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```